# Android BLE gatt.disconnect disconnects a second device

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Experiencing a very odd issue with Android BLE on a pixel device.

Consider 2 separate applications (a typical app w/ a UI and an android background service with minimal UI).  Both of these applications have a BLE library dependency, which is the BLE sdk I've written.  This SDK contains 2 separate classes for connecting to 2 different types of devices (meaning I have 2 distinct classes that implement the BluetoothGattCallback interface).

All is fine and well, I can connect to each type of device from each respective application.  HOWEVER, calling a gatt.disconnect in application A on device A not only disconnects device A, it is disconnecting device B (where the connection was established in application B).

I'm also explicitly verifying that each gatt is associated to only a single particular device (can see mDevice association in logs), and each gatt also has a different hash code indicating different instances of the gatt object across applications.

I guess I'm at a loss that the android OS seems to be causing the additional disconnect incorrectly.  I can also verify that each device is registered on its own client interface via the callback logs that occur during the connect.

How does the android OS handle the fact that this library is included in 2 applications?  I'm assuming that each app has its own "instance" of the library running in isolation.

Has anyone experienced this kind of issue (gatt.disconnect disconnects more than 1 device)?

Comment: Sounds strange. Can you reproduce the issue by using two different dev apps at the same time such as nRF Connect and LightBlue?

Comment: @Emil thank you for the idea to test with those apps.  Oddly enough, using ERF connect OR NRF connect OR Lightblue yields the same result.  When I'm connected to device A and then try to establish a connection to device B over another application, device A connection is dropped.  There's nothing in the logs for any app other than "Disconnect" event. Technically speaking , I can't even test the disconnect issue as described above in the original post due to the fact that this approach doesn't seem to let me have simultaneous connections.

Comment: Worth noting, is connection A is a bonded connection (the device fw requires a bond), while connecting to device B does not require a bond.

Comment: What pixel device do you have and which fw version (build number)?

Comment: @Emil Currently on a pixel 4XL Android V13 build number TP1A.221005.002.B2

Comment: Can you try connecting to two devices that do not require bonding? In other words, replace device A with another BLE device that is in range. This is to eliminate the possibility that the issue is related to bonding which will help get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Also, does the second disconnect happen immediately after the first one? Or do you think there's a certain amount of time that passes before the second disconnection happens?

Comment: @YoussifSaeed I can connect 2 devices that don't require bonding, but "those devices" never had the issue.  It's custom hardware as well... so device A hardware 1 requires a bond while dev B hardware 2 does not.  I might have to try and get creative w/ how I can test.
The disconnect happens immediately after the first device disconnects.  Logs are within ms.

Comment: So just to confirm, you are saying that if instead of your two custom hardware you use two devices that both don't require bonding, the issue goes away? If you don't know how to test this, you can simply use 2 phones simulating an peripher/GATT server (I believe both nRF Connect and LightBlue support this feature). At this point I am just trying to understand the full details of the bug which would be useful especially if it is related to a known Android/Pixel bug (e.g. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/273764386)

Comment: I am saying if I take 2 devices of the same type (for instance, the devices that don't require bonding) I can disconnect them just fine, one at a time, as expected.  Disconnecting 1 does not result in a disconnect of the other.  I have not explicitly tested this case w/ 2 of the "bonded" devices, but I'd imagine they will be okay as well (I'll still test to verify). I'll try and see how I can use nRF to simulate the peripheral device - I was not aware I could do this.

Comment: Update - I connected 2 of the devices that require bonding, triggered a disconnect on 1 of them WHICH DID trigger a disconnect in the second bridge.  Not sure the issues are related yet, but it was noticed today during testing.

Comment: One more test that would be very useful is to run the exact same application on a different device running a different OS. If things work on the other device/OS then this will confirm that it is an Android/Pixel bug.

Comment: @YoussifSaeed bug is reproducible on a Samsung device as well.